# Token error using Cloud Foundry API client credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am trying to create a [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com/) plugin that sends notifications for Cloud Foundry events to our chat room, but have been banging my head against API auth for a couple days. Essentially, I am trying to consume:

```sh
cf curl /v2/events
```

but am trying to make the equivalent underlying calls via Node.js rather than through [the CLI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli). From my reading of OAuth2, a read-only not-acting-on-behalf-of-a-user server-side-only app is a good use case for [client credentials](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#application-access). I couldn't find a CF client library for Node that supports client credentials so I'm trying to do it myself...unsuccessfully. Here's what I've tried, in bash:

```sh
CLIENT_ID=hubot-cf-test
CLIENT_SECRET=mysecret

uaac client add $CLIENT_ID --secret $CLIENT_SECRET --scope uaa.none --authorized_grant_types "client_credentials"
curl -X POST --user "$CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' https://uaa.mycloudfoundry.com/oauth/token

# copy in access_token value from previous response
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc..." https://api.mycloudfoundry.com/v2/events
```

which gives me

```js
{
  "code": 1000,
  "description": "Invalid Auth Token",
  "error_code": "CF-InvalidAuthToken"
}
```

What silly little thing am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

P.S. [Here](https://github.com/andypiper/hubot-cf/compare/master...18F:notifications) is my progress on the Hubot plugin, if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `~/.cf/config.json` file.  That file is used by the `cf` command to maintain it's current state.  You'll see security tokens in there: `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken`.

The `AccessToken` is what you should be using for `CLIENT_SECRET`, however that token has a **VERY** short lifetime - think minutes.  Once it's expired, you need to get a new one, using the `RefreshToken`.  So, we need to find an example that shows refreshing the token, that you can model your code after.

The authoritative reference is the source for the `cf` command itself; there's some of the code for that, here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/blob/master/cf/api/authentication/authentication.go

If you're more of a Java person, there's some code here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/blob/master/cloudfoundry-client-lib/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/client/lib/oauth2/OauthClient.java

There's more about the UAA, here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the scope `cloud_controller.admin` for your `hubot-cf-test` client? You'll need that to access the event stream, I think.